# Semantics and pragmatics

Tags: english

Many people call implicature as ambiguity and to me it is what words refer to,  I'm confused what implicature actually is and what is relationship between implicatures, entailment and presupposition. Plz.help me with elaborate easy examples I'm student I want to know all of these.